# cannot set accessibilityValue property

Tags: swift, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation, uiaccessibility

I'm trying to set an **accessibilityValue** property in swift application.
It doesn't work , while I'm trying to inspect the element with appium , the actual value is different from the value I've tried to set.

In case and I'm setting next values :

```
    self?.isAccessibilityElement = true
    self?.accessibilityLabel = "Header"
    self?.accessibilityValue = Some dynamic value
```

The value property is being override by the  **accessibilityLabel** value

Any idea what has gone wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: is some dynamic value a string ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri I've missed you :), could you elaborate your Q ?